# Is this a well formed formula?

Tags: logic

(( ∨ (¬)) → ( → ))

The reason I am unsure is because of definition 2. "we may write the string (¬ ), provided we have already written the string A," does this mean that (¬) may not be written before ?

Answer (score 2):

The formula you've written is fine. The definition is in my opinion confusingly phrased. What it should say is:

> **If $A$ is a well-formed formula**, then $(\neg A)$ is also a well-formed formula.

That is, you're not required to have already written the string $A$ in the specific sentence you're looking at (it's not a problem if $\neg q$ precedes $q$) - rather, the point is that we imagine someone compiling a list of all well-formed formulas, and whenever they put $A$ on the list they then later put "$(\neg A)$" on the list - in our process for enumerating WFFs, $(\neg A)$ is *built from* (hence *after*) $A$.

---

Closer in flavor to the definition you've been given, but in my opinion still clearer: "If we already know that $A$ is a WFF, then we can conclude that $(\neg A)$ is also a WFF." This keeps the temporal aspect explicit but (I think) does a better job of separating the *process of enumerating WFFs* from the *process of writing a single WFF*.